# Base64 encoding on iOS missing padding at the end

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

I need to send the Authentication header to a server. The server is using basic auth, so it's expecting "Authentication: Basic encodedUser:Pass". I found on StackOverflow how to encode and decode a string to Base64:

```
NSData *plainData = [plainString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String);
```

If I encode "test:test" with this it returns: `dGVzdDp0ZXN0`.

The problem is my server is expecting to receive: `dGVzdDp0ZXN0DQo=`

What's wrong with they way I'm encoding? The last `DQo=` is a padding? How do I get that padding?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dGVzdDp0ZXN0DQo= is "test:test\r\n"
```

Your input is missing a carriage return/line feed.

You can easily find a base64 decoder on the web by googling. For example

[www.base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org)